# When to use when() in Mocktio

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am writing unit tests with JUnit and Mockito. Let's say I have following test class:

```
@Mock(name="myService")
private myServiceClass myService;

@InjectMocks
private myClassIWantToTest classUnderTest;

final myModelClass myModel = new myModelClass();

@Before
private void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotiations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test 
private void testSomething(){
    myModel.setCode("someCode");

    final MyDataClass myData = new MyDataClass();
    myData.setCode("someCode");

    doReturn("someCode").when(myModel.getCode());
    doReturn(myModel).when(myService.getModelByCode("someCode"));

    assertEquals(classUnderTest.getDataByCode(eq("someCode")), myData);
    verify(myService.getModelByCode(eq("someCode")), atLeastOnce());
}
```

The method `getDataByCode` from my `classUnderTest` converts the Model into Data and it should have the same code. What is a bit blurry to me is that unit tests should encapsule the `classUnderTest` from all dependencies. But now I have a problem. I use the setter methods `myData` and `myModel` to set a value. The thing is I put a `DoReturn` in there for `myModel`, but the problem is, that it's not a injected Mock. The method I try to test unfortunately doesn't have a field, it initializes this inside the method, so I can't really address it.

And the main thing is, when the setter of for example `myModel` doesn't work anymore or so, my test as shown above, wouldn't work anymore. I guess I have three questions:

1. How hard do I need to isolate the test class? Don't I need to use the setters for the assertEquals?
2. Is there another way to deal with objects, which are initialized inside a method I want to test? What is the best way to approach such a matter?
3. Also, what would be a good pattern for structuring this? I currently initialize my expected myData result inside a test method. The thing is that this is a rather short and easy example, but I have classes where I have tons of objects and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your main problem is the design of the class you want to test. But a few things before:

```
myModel.setCode("someCode");
doReturn("someCode").when(myModel.getCode());
```

This doesn't make sense. It's not a mock, so do...when doesn't make sense here. And if it was a mock, calling the setter would be useless.

```
assertEquals(classUnderTest.getDataByCode(eq("someCode")), myData);
```

Also strange. You want to call getDataByCode, why the `eq`? Do it. Call it. Write:

```
assertEquals(classUnderTest.getDataByCode("someCode"), myData);
```

Mockito-Matchers are good when you want to verify something but normally you don't use them as parameters for real method calls.

```
verify(myService.getModelByCode(eq("someCode")), atLeastOnce());
```

Does this code really compile? Shouldn't it be ...

```
verify(myService, atLeastOnce()).getModelByCode(eq("someCode"));
```

So, it would be a good idea to actually isolate your unit tests as far as you can. The less external problems you are inviting into your test, the better the test can be.

> The method I try to test unfortunately doesn't have a field, it
>   initializes this inside the method, so I can't really address it.

This simply sounds like a code smell, but without the actual code in question, it's hard to say...

Comment: Thanks. Yes the actual code is not very well structured. But you addressed, what I meant. Since myModel isn't a mock, it makes no sense to use doReturn. But calling the setter-method is not advised, since my Unit-Test is then depending on it. The eq-part you're right, I was trying to simplify this example, so I made a little mistake there. the verify-method is ok, since getModelByCode() is returning a Model and not a void-method.